# Magento 2 How to use model function in phtml file When override phtml?

Tags: magento2, customer, model, customer-address

I want to override book.phtml file from my module and want to check if my module is enabled or not. if module is enabled then need to hide links and button from that phtml.

I have module function as below :

========================================

```
namespace Yourname\Yourmodule\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

class ModuleStatusConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    const XML_MODULE_STATUS_PATH = "setup/status/enabled"; //Example: test/general/enable

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * ModuleStatusConfigProvider constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $config = [];
        $moduleIsEnabled = $this->checkModuleIsEnable(self::XML_MODULE_STATUS_PATH);

        if($moduleIsEnabled) {
            $config['modulesStatus'] = 1;
        } else {
            $config['modulesStatus'] = 0;
        }
        return $config;
    }

    public function checkModuleIsEnable($path)
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            $path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

========================================

I want to use this model in my book.phtml file to check module is enable or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Is it working for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

**Use block method :**

Add this below code in your block file :

```
protected $_moduleManager;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
    ....
) {
    ...
    $this->_moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    ...
}
/**
 * Whether a module is enabled in the configuration or not
 *
 */
public function isModuleEnabled($moduleName)
{
    return $this->_moduleManager->isEnabled($moduleName);
}

/**
 * Whether a module output is permitted by the configuration or not
 *
 */
public function isOutputEnabled($moduleName)
{
    return $this->_moduleManager->isOutputEnabled($moduleName);
}
```

Then, call this below code in your phtml file :

```
echo $block->isModuleEnabled('YourNamespace_YourModule');
echo $block->isOutputEnabled('YourNamespace_YourModule');
```

If you want to direct use in phtml file then use this below code :

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$moduleManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Module\Manager');
if($moduleManager->isOutputEnabled('YourNamespace_YourModule')){
    //the module output is enabled
} else {
    //the module output is disabled
}
```

**Note : Don't use Object Manager Directly.**